# Error while deploying Node js application to Vercel

Tags: node.js, vercel

**Trying to deploy Node server to Vercel but getting the following error:**

[image]

**The structure:**

[image]

**Besides the versel.json file is present:**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

**So what could be the reason for the error?**